# Django Rest Framework - How to POST when using ListCreateAPIView

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am kind of bemused on how to perform what I think I should be able to work out but after a few hours I am at a loss. I am learning Django and DRF so everything seems a struggle.

I have written an API using the Django Rest Framework. I am able to perform GET requests but not PUSH requests on `NOTE Serializer` (I can push to the `STOCK serializer` fine). Based on the code i have written (using instructions from the Django Rest Framework website), when I attempt to POST using the following command:

```
http POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/notes/ note='api test' {"stock":"test"} 'Authorization: Token 1235454545656'
```

I get the following error:

```
HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request
Allow: GET, POST, HEAD, OPTIONS
Content-Type: application/json
Date: Sat, 27 May 2017 14:51:52 GMT
Server: WSGIServer/0.2 CPython/3.6.0
Vary: Accept
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN

{
    "stock": [
        "This field is required."
    ]
}
```

I know it is required... that's why i included it in the PUSH request! Can someone explain what i am doing wrong and how to correct it?

This is my `book/models.py`:

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
import uuid

class Stock(models.Model):
    '''
    Model representing the stock info.
    '''
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    book_code = models.CharField(max_length=14, null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.book_code

class Note(models.Model):
    '''
    Model representing the stock note.
    '''
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    note = models.TextField(max_length=560)
    stock = models.ForeignKey(Stock)
    date_note_created = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.note
```

This is my `api/serializer.py`:

```
from bookstock.models import Stock, Note
from rest_framework import serializers

class StockSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Stock
        fields = ('id', 'user', 'book_code')

class NoteSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    stock = StockSerializer(many=True)
    user = serializers.HiddenField(default=serializers.CurrentUserDefault())


    class Meta:
        model = Note
        fields = ('user', 'note', 'stock', 'date_note_created')
```

This is my `api/views.py`:

```
from rest_framework import generics
from bookstock.models import Stock, Note
from api.serializers import StockSerializer
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticated

class StockList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = StockSerializer
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)

    def get_queryset(self):
        user = self.request.user
        return Stock.objects.filter(user=user)

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(user=self.request.user, )

    def perform_update(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(user=self.request.user)

class NoteList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = NoteSerializer
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated, )

    def get_queryset(self):
        user = self.request.user
        return Note.objects.filter(user=user)

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(data=self.request.data)

    def perform_update(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(data=self.request.data)
```

This is my `api/urls.py`:

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from api import views
from rest_framework.authtoken.views import obtain_auth_token

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^v1/stocks/$', views.StockList.as_view()),
    url(r'^v1/notes/$', views.NoteList.as_view()),
    url(r'^v1/api-token-auth/', obtain_auth_token),
    url(r'v1/api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls', namespace='rest_framework')),

]
```

What have i done wrong?

Comment: stock must be a list of stocks... it cant be a dict... since you added many=True in your serializer, the serializer expects the stock to be a list of dicts..

Comment: Hi Fazil, thanks for the suggestion but even if I remove main=True, i still get the same error. If change the HTTP post to a list `http POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/notes/ note='api test' stock=["test"] 'Authorization: Token 1235454545656'`, i get a different error: `{
    "stock": [
        "Incorrect type. Expected pk value, received str."
    ]
}`. Any other suggestions?

Comment: what's the data you actually need to pass through the stock field in the serializer? Is "test" book_code or user??

Comment: The data to pass is "test" which is the book_code (field in the Stock model).

Comment: I have added my answer. further comments are preferred to be posted there please..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I went back to basics and started again with DRF. First i turned off Token Authentication and used basic auth for testing. Second, I tried to PUSH using the Browsable API instead of cURL/HTTPie. I found that i was not able to PUSH using the Browsable API either.

This told me the problem was not with the syntax for cURL/HTTPie and ultimately I posted a separate [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44997315/django-rest-framework-got-a-typeerror-when-calling-note-objects-create?noredirect=1#comment76968849_44997315) regarding the issue with the Browsable API. Once that was resolved I was able to POST/PUT/DELETE via Browsable API and cURL/HTTPie. I had a separate issue with respect to PUSHing when a User is not the object owner which is answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45128646/django-rest-framework-deny-user-from-push-when-user-is-not-object-owner/45176627#45176627).

In short, this problem is now solved as a consequence of two other questions/answers.

Answer (score 0):

When you need to post data through the NoteSerializer, your data need to be in this format,

```
{
    "user": "some_user",
    "note": "some_note",
    "date_created": "28-05-2017", #some_date
    "stock": [
                {
                    "id": "2", #some_id
                    "user": "some_user",
                    "book_code": "some_book_code"
                },
                {
                    "id": "3", #some_id
                    "user": "some_user",
                    "book_code": "some_book_code"
                }
             ]
}
```

Serializer will raise error, if its not in this format. For each field in the serializer, required=True is set as default by django.

Else, you need to remove the fields from the Stock serializer whichever that are not required.

Comment: Thanks Fazil. Syntactically, using HTTPIE or even CURL, what would the syntax be? Presume there is a stock `book_code` called `Test` in the database which i need the note to reference. The way you have described it and based on the model and views, I expect three fields to be populated by model/views, the `user`, `date_created` and the `id`. So the only thing i need to provide is the `note` and the `stock` i want the note _against_ (`Test` in this case).