# Django Rest Framework - "Got a `TypeError` when calling `Note.objects.create()'"

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

When i am trying to POST using the browsable API of DRF, i get the following error:

> Got a `TypeError` when calling `Note.objects.create()`. This may be
>   because you have a writable field on the serializer class that is not
>   a valid argument to `Note.objects.create()`. You may need to make the
>   field read-only, or override the NoteSerializer.create() method to
>   handle this correctly.

I don't know what is generating this error or how to overcome it. Literally spent hours google searching or changing the code. Can someone explain how to overcome this error? (Please note i am new to Django and DRF!)

Here is the `models.py`:

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
import uuid

class Stock(models.Model):
    '''
    Model representing the stock info.
    '''
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    book_code = models.CharField(max_length=14, null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.book_code

class Note(models.Model):
    '''
    Model representing the stock note.
    '''
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    note = models.TextField(max_length=560)
    stock = models.ForeignKey(Stock, related_name='notes')
    date_note_created = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.note
```

This is the `views.py`:

```
from rest_framework import generics
from stocknoter.models import Stock, Note
from api.serializers import StockSerializer, NoteSerializer

# Create your views here.

class StockList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = StockSerializer
    def get_queryset(self):
        user = self.request.user
        return Stock.objects.filter(user=user)

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(user=self.request.user)

    def perform_update(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(user=self.request.user)


class NoteList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = NoteSerializer
    def get_queryset(self):
        user = self.request.user
        return Note.objects.filter(user=user)

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(data=self.request.data)

    def perform_update(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(data=self.request.data)
```

This is the `serializers.py`:

```
from stocknoter.models import Stock, Note
from rest_framework import serializers

class StockSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = serializers.HiddenField(default=serializers.CurrentUserDefault())
    notes = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(read_only=True)


    class Meta:
        model = Stock
        fields = ('id', 'user', 'book_code', 'notes')

class NoteSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = serializers.HiddenField(default=serializers.CurrentUserDefault())

    class Meta:
        model = Note
        fields = ('user', 'note', 'stock')
```

Comment: Try to add `many=True` as argument: `notes = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(read_only=True, many=True)`

Comment: @neverwalkaloner, thanks for the reply. Made the change but unfortunately made no difference. Appreciate any other suggestions.

Comment: Can you show data you are trying to post?

Comment: Via the Browsable API I am inputting text for the Note as 'Test' and for the Stock i am selecting an existing object of 'TST'.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think this is because you are providing keyword argument `data` to save method. This is unnecessary. `save()` dont have such argument. Try just this:

```
def perform_create(self, serializer):
    serializer.save()
```

Comment: Wow, that's worked! I am sure i put those args in there for a reason but it's been so long i can't remember why. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

take a **print()** of **serializer_data** in the **view.py**
to see what you actually sending to model and create.
then in your **serializer.py** override the **create** method..
for example:

```
def post(self, request):
    print(serializer_data.validated_data)


def create(self, validated_data):
    del validated_data['c']
    return X.objects.create(a=validated_data['a'],
                            b=validated_data['b'],
                            )
```