# Django Rest Framework - Deny User from PUSH when User is not Object Owner

Tags: python-3.x, django-rest-framework

At the moment i have permissions set which prevent a user from GET, DELETE and PUT if they are not the Object Owner of `Stock`. But for some reason, the permissions do not work when the user performs a PUSH i.e. any user can PUSH a `Note` to a `Stock` even if they are not the `Stock Owner`.

Why? And how do i properly check that when a `User` PUSHs a `Note`, they must be the Owner of `Stock`?

---

This is an example data PUSH sent via `HTTPie`:

```
http -a testuser:testpw POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/notes/ note="Testing API" stock="36"
```

Where "36" is the stock_id for an existing Stock.

Here is the `stock_note/models.py`:

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
import uuid

class Stock(models.Model):
    '''
    Model representing the stock info.
    '''
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    book_code = models.CharField(max_length=14, null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.book_code

class Note(models.Model):
    '''
    Model representing the stock note.
    '''
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    note = models.TextField(max_length=560)
    stock = models.ForeignKey(Stock, related_name='notes')
    date_note_created = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.note
```

This is the `api/serializers.py`:

```
from stock_note.models import Stock, Note
from rest_framework import serializers

class StockSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = serializers.HiddenField(default=serializers.CurrentUserDefault())
    notes = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(read_only=True, many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Stock
        fields = ('id', 'user', 'book_code', 'notes')

class NoteSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = serializers.HiddenField(default=serializers.CurrentUserDefault())

    class Meta:
        model = Note
        fields = ('user', 'note', 'stock')
```

This is the `api/views.py`:

```
from rest_framework import generics
from stock_note.models import Stock, Note
from api.serializers import StockSerializer, NoteSerializer
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticated
from api.permissions import IsOwner

# Create your views here.

class StockList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = StockSerializer
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated, IsOwner)

    def get_queryset(self):
        user = self.request.user
        return Stock.objects.filter(user=user)

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save()

    def perform_update(self, serializer):
        serializer.save()

class NoteList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = NoteSerializer
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated, IsOwner)

    def get_queryset(self):
        user = self.request.user
        return Note.objects.filter(user=user)

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save()

    def perform_update(self, serializer):
        serializer.save()

class StockListDetail(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    serializer_class = StockSerializer
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated, IsOwner)
    lookup_url_kwarg = 'stock_id'

    def get_queryset(self):
        stock = self.kwargs['stock_id']
        return Stock.objects.filter(id=stock)

class NoteListDetail(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    serializer_class = NoteSerializer
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated, IsOwner)
    lookup_url_kwarg = 'note_id'

    def get_queryset(self):
        note = self.kwargs['note_id']
        return Note.objects.filter(id=note)
```

This is the `api/permissions.py`:

```
from rest_framework import permissions

class IsOwner(permissions.BasePermission):
    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        return request.user and request.user.is_authenticated()

    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
        return obj.user == request.user
```

And finally this is the `api/urls.py`:

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from api import views

urlpatterns = [
    #Endpoint to allow GET and POST stocks.
    url(r'^v1/stocks/$', views.StockList.as_view()),
    #Endpoint to allow GET and POST a note to a stock.
    url(r'^v1/notes/$', views.NoteList.as_view()),
    #Endpoint to allow GET, POST, PUSH, DELETE a stocknote
    url(r'^v1/stocks/(?P<stock_id>[0-9]+)/$', views.StockListDetail.as_view()),
    #Endpoint to allow GET, POST, PUSH, DELETE a Note
    url(r'^v1/notes/(?P<note_id>[0-9]+)/$', views.NoteListDetail.as_view()),
]
```

---

**UPDATE:**

Following on from Tom's answer the NoteSerializer now looks like this which means a User is now only able to PUSH a Note if they are the Owner of Stock (the new addition is the validate_stock function). Keep note that there is one difference between Tom's answer and this code: instead of just checking the `value`, i am checking for the `value.id`. This is explained further in the comments of the validate_stock function:

```
class NoteSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = serializers.HiddenField(default=serializers.CurrentUserDefault())

    class Meta:
        model = Note
        fields = ('user', 'note', 'stock')

    def validate_stock(self, value):
        '''
        This function checks if the User is the owner of Stock
        before allowing the User to PUSH a Note to the Stock.
        '''

        # You have to get the object ID because otherwise you get following error when
        # you try to perform Stock.object.get(...):
        #TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'Stock'
        value_id = value.id

        stock_obj = Stock.objects.get(pk=value_id)
        user = self.context['request'].user

        if not stock_obj.user == user:
            raise serializers.ValidationError("You do not have permission to perform this action.")
        return value
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you `POST` to `v1/notes/` the only permission check that will run is `has_permission`. There's no existing instance being referred to in the URL, so `get_object` isn't called on the view, and the `has_object_permission` check isn't called (there's no instance to call it with.)

What you need for this case is to enforce validation on the serializer class that ensures that the stock value must correspond to a Stock instance that is owned by the user.

Something along these lines...

```
def validate_stock(self, value):
    stock = Stock.objects.get(pk=value)
    user = self.context['request'].user
    if not stock.user == user:
        raise serializers.ValidationError(...)
    return value
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Tom. I am guessing the validation enforcement needs to occur in the NoteSerializer. When i take the code you provided above and insert into the NoteSerializer i get the following error:

`TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'Stock'`

Unsure why this error is raised now? 

Please keep in mind i am new to Django and DRF so apologies if i have not understood your answer correctly.

Comment: A bit of debugging and it looks like DRF generates the mentioned TypeError if i simply did this:  

`def validate_stock(self, value):  
    stock = Stock.objects.get(pk=value)`

Comment: Just to wanted to add that it took several hours of debugging(!) but I eventually resolved the `TypeError` by checking for the `value.id` instead of just `value`. I have updated my original post with the new code in case anyone encounters a similar issue. Once again, thanks for your help Tom.